# Python Pandas: Select inverse of dataframe grouby

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas data frame called `df_all`.
I then wish to group by columns `Foo`, and select only the last row for each grouped by set:

```py
# E.g. 
# Foo Bar Baz
#  1   1   1
#  1   2   2
#  2   1   2
#  2   3   4
#  2   5   6
# Wish to select rows '1 2 3' and '2 5 6' since if we group by Foo,
# they are the last fow for each distinct Foo value
df_slice = df_all.groupby('Foo').last()
```

The above works, now I wish to have the set of rows that are in df_all, and not in `df_slice`, this is what I tried:

```py
dv_inverse = df[~df_slice.isin(df_all)].dropna(how = 'all')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
df_inverse = df_all[df_all.duplicated(subset='Foo', keep='last')] 
print(df_inverse)
```

```
   Foo  Bar  Baz
0    1    1    1
2    2    1    2
3    2    3    4
```

Comment: What an elegant one liner!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverted mask for `df_slice` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df_all['Foo'].duplicated(keep='last')
dv_inverse = df_all[m]
print (dv_inverse)
   Foo  Bar  Baz
0    1    1    1
2    2    1    2
3    2    3    4

df_slice = df_all[~m]
print (df_slice)
   Foo  Bar  Baz
1    1    2    2
4    2    5    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `groupby.tail` to construct `df_slice`; then use `index.isin` to filter `df_all` for `dv_inverse`:

```py
df_slice = df_all.groupby('Foo').tail(1)
dv_inverse = df_all[~df_all.index.isin(df_slice.index)]
```

Output:

```
   Foo  Bar  Baz
0    1    1    1
2    2    1    2
3    2    3    4
```